# Change "From" email address when sending to a specific domain

Tags: email, exchange-2003

I would like to set up Exchange so that when a user (e.g. user@mydomain.com) sends an email to somedomain.com Exchange makes the email appear to have come from other_user@mydomain.com.

This would have to be done on a per-domain basis, and invisibly to the user. So all emails come from user@mydomain.com, except emails to somedomain.com, which appear to come from other_user@mydomain.com.

If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it.

Cheers,

RB.

Answer (score 1):

In Exchange 2003 you're going to have to implement a transport event sink (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123644(EXCHG.65).aspx for details) to do what you're looking for. There isn't any built-in functionality to do this, but such an event sink wouldn't be *that* hard to develop.

(If you have plans for Exchange 2007 or 2010 be aware that transport event sinks are no longer supported in those releases, too.)